# cpan error in FreeBSD

Tags: perl, freebsd

I am using FreeBSD9.1.

There is:

```
root@BSD:/root # cpan
Can't load '/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/mach/auto/Socket/Socket.so' for module Socket: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/mach/auto/Socket/Socket.so: Undefined symbol "PL_unitcheckav" at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/XSLoader.pm line 71.
 at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/mach/Socket.pm line 852
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/Net/Ping.pm line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/Net/Ping.pm line 12.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/CPAN/Mirrors.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/CPAN/Mirrors.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/CPAN/FirstTime.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/CPAN/FirstTime.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/CPAN/HandleConfig.pm line 573.
```

why? how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Its more admin question than programming. Did you upgraded Perl from ports? If yes, you should run `perl-after-upgrade` script. If this doesnt help, check where is Socket.so:

```
 locate Socket.so
```

Check Perl version in path of .so. It should be equal to Perl version in your `/etc/make.conf` file.